# rdiff-backup on Windows: source from volume root, ignore $recycle.bin and "System Volume Information"

Tags: windows, backup, rdiff-backup

I'm trying to use rdiff-backup in Windows, using the root of a local disk as a source and a local folder on a different local disk as a destination.

rdiff-backup keeps crashing when it tries reading the "System Volume Information" folder; I am trying to discover what syntax may cause it to ignore that one, and "$RECYCLE.BIN" as well; I tried giving an ignore file with those absolute paths in it, with paths with those prefixed with ** to try and match any files like that, ran an experiment to see if it would ignore those if I created them in a test folder (which succeeded), etc.

So, is there a syntax that will cause rdiff-backup to ignore those in the root of a mounted drive?

As a starting point I tried:

```
rdiff-backup backup --ignore 'y:/$RECYCLE.BIN' --ignore 'y:/System Volume Information' y:/ z:/backup-y
```

but had no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try not to use `--ignore` but `--exclude`, with the path in double quotes and the drive letter in caps, I don't use the backup keyword and I call it from the root folder to be backed up. i.e.:

`rdiff-backup  --exclude "Y:/$RECYCLE.BIN" --exclude "y:/System Volume Information" y:/ z:/backup-y`

and it works. I'm using rdiff-bakup version 2.0.5

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  It's not clear to me how to do this with the newer syntax.